# Array reduce in typescript with object

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to give my reducer a return value in typescript.
The output would be:
Instead of any waht would I set acc to?
How would I set my return type with the output been {temp: 60, temp: 60} ?

```
 return array.reduce((acc, curr: string):any => {
    const key = 'temp;
    acc[key] = 60;
    return acc;
  }, {});
```

Yes I'm aware that the key and value are the same every iteration. I'm just using it as an example for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of any

`(acc, curr: string): { [key: string]: YourTypeHere }`

Comment: Thanks Adrian what would acc be ?

Comment: Same, that is the return type of the function that returns the accumulator. Pretty sure the compiler will infer they accumulator type from the functions return type.

Comment: acc[key] = 60;  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.

Comment: Let me run up a StackBlitz

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I also tried adding it like this too. acc: { [key: string]: number} but then I get Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Comment: Thanks for that Adrian, that's exactly what I have but i'm getting. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'. when I rollover acc[key] = 60;

Comment: In your example you have this. { [key: string]: string. shouldn't it be { [key: string]: number ? Seen as my value is a number.